# Best ways to design a kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer

Need a help in getting the best design solution for creating Kafka consumers.

Will be having multiple topics and those can be like groups say for example
10 topics that are used to send out **emails** (10 count is chosen because will be getting more client traffic and want to dedicate a topic per client like each topic for one client so that others will not be delayed or waited)

10 topics to process a **business logic** and the 10 count explanation is same as above.

Now with this usage what's the best way to design Kafka consumers? Consumer dedicated to each topic ? or is there a way where we can scale up consumer dynamically by passing in which topic it needs to subscribe? For sure will be deploying this in containers but want suggestions on how to get started with consumer part with dynamic scalability and common code. And what's the best technology to implement this type of kafka consumers? (dotnet/java/python) ?

Also please do suggest if partitions make sense in this kind of design so that we can leverage consumer groups.

Comment: In several cases "topic per client" isn't a good design, especially when you reach tens of thousands of clients. You can use separate topics for event handling of "email-sent" or "email-read", with some cross-referential value, but those events would be separate from the actual SMTP email client traffic

Answer (score 0):

Consumers belonging to a same consumer group are assigned partitions in a topic.

In kafka, a topic can have multiple partitions. The consumers consume the messages of a particular topic from their assigned partition(s). The messages in the partition are  ordered by sequential offsets.

Now, topic-wide record order is not important, you generally want to start with a higher number of partitions in a topic. Let's say start with 100 partitions. Your data will be distributed across the 100 partitions in a topic, assuming null keys or at least 100 unique key values with non colliding hashes, as record keys determine partitioning. If topic order is important, you're limited to one partition, and therefore one consumer thread; however, this thread can separate consumption from processing by loading records into alternative data structures (a queue) for processing.

You can now have 10 consumers consuming from 100 partitions. Each consumer will be assigned to about 10 partitions, and they will consume the messages in a round-robin fashion.

If you want to scale out, you simply increase the number of consumers. If you double the number of consumer to 20 then each consumer will process 5 partitions, thus, you get double throughput.

Comment: Always keep the partition count high if you are unsure of the volume and expected to be on higher side as mentioned above. Also, if you are using any stateful operations in consumers then altering partition count is a pain. So always keep an optimum partition count based on some performance tests

Comment: sure will go with higher no of partitions for sure and also I don't believe we need ordering here. But any technology suggestion while writing this consumer service code?

Comment: Also I am looking a way to achieve message delaying, because in some cases we want the processing of the message to be delayed. I know Kafka is super good for millions of message processing with a little delay, but is there any architecture where I can introduce a DB to persist the delayed message and process them when the delay meets? any thoughts on this implementation?